Ubuntu Failing to Install and Lost All My Drive Data
I tried installing Ubuntu 15 times, but every attempt failed. On the next startup, I just tried Ubuntu instead of installing and downloaded a program with iso type.
And accidentally selected mount in disk.. and my D drive which had 800 GB of data, and my Windows system got deleted (The disk was hdd). But my c drive is ok
So now, whenever I start up my laptop, I get the "Hard Disk 3F0 boot device not found" error.
...
Is there anything I can do?
Can I recover my data?
And should I reinstall Windows?
"This issue is different from others because at least Ubuntu is installed for them, but my laptop has neither Windows nor Ubuntu, so that's why I'm asking.
I think the information i giving is not enough so if you needed to know something, say it"
Pardon my English.

This question is similar to: How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Welcome to ASK. You still have the install media to boot from. If you select 'Try Ubuntu' this should allow you to mount the other partitions and check the status of all your data. If it has gone its gone but it is more than likely still there and all you have done is broken the install process which may be fixed. You need to add much more data regarding what you did to install Ubuntu, details of your hardware and any crash results you have while attempting it. In my experience I would re-install Windows as a last resort as for me anyway, it does tend to loose data. (Win is off topic here.)
